# How to build a list of nested dictionaries and lists

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested-lists

I am trying to create a list of dictionaries with other nested lists of dictionaries. Here is what the list should look like when completed...

```
[{'key':'value'},{'key':[{'key':'value'},{'key':'value'},]},]
```

Here is the code I am working with:

```
dict1={}
list1=[]
dict2={}
list2=[]

for obj1 in some_list:
    dict1['key'] = value

    for obj2 in some_other_list:                
        dict2['key'] = value
        dict2['key'] = value
        dict2['key'] = value
        dict2['key'] = value
        dict2['key'] = value
        list2.append(dict2.copy())

    dict1['key'] = list2
    list1.append(dict1)
```

My results are that list2 keeps accumulating and not clearing after iterating through some_other_list.

Comment: Where did you expect it to be cleared? Does this all sit in some larger loop?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... Edited my code above to show the nested for loop... No larger loop... obj1 has 2 iterations, and obj2 has 4 iterations.

Comment: Is that indentation correct? Should the last two lines be inside the outer for loop? You only assign e.g. `list2 = []` *outside* the loops, so it's not obvious why you'd expect it to be cleared at any point.

Comment: Just made that edit to the last two lines...

Comment: For each assignment of `dict2['key'] = value` beyond the first, you are clearly the last value. Is this what you intend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never specify that `list2` *should* be cleared. I think you want something like:

```
for obj1 in some_list:
    dict1['key'] = value

    for obj2 in some_other_list:                
        ...

    dict1['key'] = list2
    list2 = [] # create new list to fill next time
    list1.append(dict1)
```

Note that this replaces whatever `value` is with `list2`; you don't need to "initialise" the key, you can leave that line out entirely (which would probably be clearer).

Comment: Your a life saver... I've been wrestling with this all morning... Time for some coffee now...

Comment: No problem. You could do the same thing with `dict2`, then you don't need the `.copy` and you don't risk odd side-effects if not all keys are replaced.